# More important than !important (a higher level !important)?

Tags: html, css, css-cascade

The title says most of it. Is there a CSS keyword which overrides `!important` at one higher level or is there some feature like this planned in any newer CSS spec?

Of course, I know that `!important` is a bit likely to be used by noobs and that in many cases it is not the best way to go as stylesheets may really suck if badly written. However, sometimes it's useful and even needed.

The strongest style in CSS I can think of is an inline style with `!important` like this:

```
<span id="bluebeaver" style="color: red !important;">I am a happy blue beaver</span>
```

Now let's assume that I cannot edit the HTML and must modify the style from an external stylesheet.

It would be really great to have something like:

```
#bluebeaver {
    color: blue !important 2;
}
```

If they had levels for it like for instance with `z-index`.

Is there any solution to this or anything planned with newer CSS specifications? 
So far I did not find anything.

Can you show a CSS solution to override an `!important` inline style or is there definitely no possibility?

Comment: why should you use !important on inline style on the first place ? a misunderstanding of the use of CSS ? If it is because of a javascript , then , the good practice is to add/remove class and not reset CSS on the fly ....

Comment: No, thankfully, there is no super-plus-important. And this question is, I think, basically a clear demonstration of the problems caused through the cavalier, inconsiderate, use of the `!important` key word.

Comment: From [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/): "The only way an !important value can be overridden is with another !important rule declared later in the CSS and with equal or great specificity value otherwise".

Comment: *sometimes its[sic] useful and even needed* [citation needed] After 20 years working in CSS, I've yet to find a place where I've had to use `!important`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Example: Inline styles must be overwritten from external stylesheet :-)

Furthermore in some cases where you have bloated CSS files with thousands of rules (usually from Themeforest template creators or from SASS generated CSS) then it just saves you countless hours of overwriting all this rules.

Comment: @Blackbam The solution to these problems is to a) not use inline styles and b) be more systematic in creating your CSS. The solution is not to compound the problem by adding more CSS rules. This is a bit like paving a paved road because it has some potholes. Then, when that gets potholes, pave it again, until you need a ladder to cross the road from the sidewalk, and everyone's axles are breaking. There's a reason that they tear up the roads every once in a while.

Comment: If too much is declared important, nothing is important any more. Maybe your problem has a different root cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no keyword or other way to make a declaration more important than `!important`. There is no known activity to change this.

In general, it is possible to override a declaration that has `!important` by using a rule that also has it and that has higher specificity. However, a declaration in a `style` attribute has, by definition, higher specificity than any other author declaration. The only way to defeat it is in CSS is to use a *user* style sheet with `!important`.

There are non-CSS solutions, but they are rather obvious, such as using JavaScript to simply remove or modify the `style` attribute.

Comment: Also see [CSS cascade order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#complete_cascade_order).

Answer (score 5):

Simply remove the `style` attribute from the element using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("bluebeaver").removeAttribute('style');
```

Then use your external stylesheet to apply whatever CSS you want.

---

***Two reasons why creating higher levels of `!important` is not a good idea:***

1. It sets a bad precedent.

   Adding `!important2` would be caving in to poor-coding habits on a global scale. It would be the W3C sending a signal that anything goes.

   You've also opened the door to `!important3`, `!important4`, etc. Where does it end?

   Lowering standards and expectations is not a good way for the industry to make progress.
2. It may not even solve your problem.

   Consider this: The person who set that inline style to `color: red !important`, obviously wanted that rule to have the highest priority.

   If your idea became real, and there were higher levels of `!important`, let's say going up to `!important10`, guess what that person would have used? And you'd still have the same problem, but you'd be here asking if there were any plans for `!important11`.

Comment: Good answer. By the way, I have seen lots of time z-index: 99999; in a page with z-index problems ...

Comment: Yes. I am forced to follow this because my other developer adds `1important` in his code and then again he follows the same `1important` technique to override mine. I can't even communicate to him as he ignores it and may point me to this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22815 where the author himself has given a lazy reply for god-knows-what reason.  Makes it even more confusing unless DevTools gives a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

The highest order I know of is targeting elements that have inline styles applied. You can actually select the element's `style` data attribute in the CSS selector to override its style! Check this out:

```css
.blue[style]{
  color:blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue" style="color:red;">SO VERY IMPORTANT</div>
```

Of course you can even get more specific by targeting the style specifically, such as `.blue[style="color:red;"]`.

Comment: A good answer anyway it does not help in the case described: `<div class="blue" style="color:red !important;">SO VERY IMPORTANT</div>`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If the `!important` winds up in the inline style, then it becomes the applied style. However, I must admit, I don't think I've ever seen it done this way. Most assume that the inline style will take precedence and therefore do not go the extra step to include important.

Comment: Yes thats true luckily. But what if the author of the HTML file wanted to prohibit the overwriting of the color?

Comment: I suppose that could be a use-case but again generally, the author of the HTML is also the author of the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the colour of HTML element using javascript.

```
document.getElementById('bluebeaver').style.color=blue;
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/041fhz07/

Comment: Definitely works, but the question states that one "...must modify the style from an external stylesheet".

Comment: If from external stylesheet then there is nothing above !important.

Answer (score 0):

Try Specificity: If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity wins.

Try to style your element the more specific you can. Maybe use:

```
 #bluebeaver span {}
```

Take a look to this link: [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: The specificity is true. This obviously will not work ;-)

Comment: Its true, thats why it works as @fauxserious proposed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use CSS only you just declare the new style with `!important`, the last "important" wins. though I'd avoid using it in the first place unless completely necessary.

it should only be used for styles that are essential for your page/app to work, not things that are expected to change.

another solution is to use JS to remove and/or add classes/id to change the style of the element when you don't want to change the CSS itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.prop1.imp1.imp2 {
  background-color: red !important;
}

div.prop1 {
  background-color: black;
}

div.prop1.imp1 {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

If you can't do this since not all elements have the .imp1 class on the list in JavaScript, and you are adding say a highlight on something with a button click (.imp2) . You can specify the 'more important' .imp2 class above the others with !important on it.

This makes the property with the additional imp2 class more important than the .prop1.imp1 style because it is loaded first in the css.